# convert std::string to const BYTE* for RegSetValueEx()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stl, registry

I have a function that gets a std::string. That function calls

[RegSetValueEx](http://www.google.be/search?q=RegSetValueEx)

the 5th parameter is the value of the registry value and expects a variable of type const BYTE*.
So I have to convert the std::string to const BYTE* and also give the length of the resulting array as the 6th parameter.

I have found a way to do it, but it feels ugly and I don't really understand what is going on. Here is a slimmed down version of that function:

```
void function(const std::string& newValue)
{
    HKEY keyHandle;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("some key"),0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&keyHandle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::wstring wNewValue;
        wNewValue.assign(newValue.begin(),newValue.end());

        if (RegSetValueEx(keyHandle, TEXT("some value"), NULL, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)(LPCTSTR)(wNewValue.c_str()), wNewValue.size()*2)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            //do something
        }
        RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    }
}
```

As you can see, i first make a wide string (UNICODE is defined), then use a double cast, and for the length i have to do *2, else it will only set half of the input string.

Is this form of cast the normal/best way to do it?

Why the * 2, what would be a better way?

Comment: Since you used a wstring, you know that the underlying type is wchar_t, and c_str() will return wchar_t*.  So no need to cast to LPCTSTR.

Answer (score 10):

```
void function(const std::string& newValue)
{
    HKEY keyHandle;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("some key"),0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&keyHandle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {

        if (RegSetValueExA(keyHandle, "some value", NULL, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)newValue.c_str(), newValue.size() + 1)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
                //do something
        }
        RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    }
}
```

I removed the part where you convert your string to a wstring, instead you'll be using the ANSI version of RegSetValueEx explicitly.

quote from RegSetValueEx remarks in MSDN:

> If dwType is the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ,
>   or REG_EXPAND_SZ type and the ANSI
>   version of this function is used
>   (either by explicitly calling
>   RegSetValueExA or by not defining
>   UNICODE before including the Windows.h
>   file), the data pointed to by the
>   lpData parameter must be an ANSI
>   character string. The string is
>   converted to Unicode before it is
>   stored in the registry.

Also note that the cbData parameter should include the size of the null termination aswell.

Comment: If you're explicitly using the ANSI version, you shouldn't use the TEXT() macro, which will expand to L"foo" if UNICODE is defined.

Comment: So as long as I don't use any non-ANSI characters I'm just fine using the ANSI versions of winapi functions? (that seems logical, but I didn't think of that)

Comment: the Win32API functions that expect text are divided to ANSI (ends with A in the function name) and Unicode (ends with W), most of them anyway. so you could use std::string with the A's and std::wstring with the W's.

Comment: @ejac: your example would not have worked if your input has characters outside of (probably) ASCII anyway since you were doing a bitwise expansion with `wNewValue.assign(newValue.begin(), newValue.end())`. Remember that wNewValue is a UNICODE character sequence so the bitwise assignment will only work if all of the character points in newValue are valid UNICODE code points. In other words, newValue contains ONLY ISO-8859-1 characters.

Answer (score 3):

The * 2 is because `RegSetValueEx` wants to know the number of bytes to write und each char (wchar_t) in a wstring is two bytes wide. So the resulting byte-array has twice the size!

Comment: It's more portable to use "sizeof _TCHAR" insetad of 2. :-D

Comment: So it would be better to write wNewValue.size()*sizeof(wchar_t) to make it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `wNewValue.size()*2+2` ? The +2 for the null character?
MSDN says: The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could also copy the unicode string into a byte array:

```
LPWSTR pData = L"SampleGrabber";
int dwSize = wcslen(pData)*sizeof(TCHAR);
BYTE slump[256];
memset((void*) slump, 0, 256*sizeof(BYTE));
memcpy((void*) slump, (const void *) pData, dwSize*sizeof(BYTE));

globit = RegSetValueEx(hKey, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*) slump, dwSize);
```

If you had the misfortune to be writing code for a WINCE 5.0 device and it lacked part of the regedit API.